Unknown spawn error in electrong-react app
I am making an app in electron and react. The app was working fine until one day this random error popped.
Description of error
I tried deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling it but it didnot help. I also updated npm and node to their latest verisons. Still the same error is persisting! Any help is highly appreciated..

I came up with the solution. In my case, node wanted to access the shell but was unable to do so. Go into the file "node_modules\cross-env\src\index.js" and check for command 'shell: shell.options'. Now, convert the command to 'shell: true'.
It worked for me.
